# Why is StringSplitOptions tagged with the Flags attribute in C#?

Tags: c#, enum-flags

I was looking at the summary of the [StringSplitOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=netframework-4.8) enum and and then was surprised to see it has the [Flags](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netframework-4.8) attribute applied to it.

The Flags enum is relevant for things like `BindingFlags` where you'd like to do things like `BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic` but in `StringSplitOptions`'s case using `StringSplitOptions.None | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` doesn't look correct.

So what are the reasons to use the `Flags` attribute on a Enum like `StringSplitOptions` that has only two different values one of them being "no value" (None) ?

Comment: It's either a mistake, or they might have done it to be forward compatible for the future in case they add new values.

Comment: The latter, I'm sure. There's only *one* option to opt into right now, but in the future there could well be more.

Comment: @Sean "forward compatible" ... but it doesn't _do_ anything, unless you print it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`StringSplitOptions` is conceptually a flags enum, even if it only has one flag *right now*.

In the future, they might add more options to `StringSplitOptions`. These new options would be added as flags, and you would be able to combine them with `RemoveEmptyEntries`.

So, it makes sense to pre-emptively mark `StringSplitOptions` with `[Flags]`.

Comment: Why would the pre-emptiv mark be necessary? Declaring an enum with [Flags] is no breaking change and can be done at any point or?

Comment: @RandRandom Why not do it now, since it's conceptually a flags enum? What's the point of waiting until later?

Comment: But wouldn't that be true for any enum? So, are you implying that every enum should be declared with [Flags] just in case you ever want to use it as flag, so why is that enum any special? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @RandRandom Some enums are written as a finite set of options, and some are written as flags enums. Those are conceptually different things. It's obvious that if further members were added to `StringSplitOptions`, they would be added as flags. So `StringSplitOptions` is conceptually a flags enum.

Comment: Can you elaborate why it is so obvious that this enum is a flag, dont see that?!?

Comment: @RandRandom `RemoveEmptyEntries` is a boolean value -- either do it, or don't. You're not going to add another option which you select *instead* of `RemoveEmptyEntries`: it wouldn't make sense to restrict users to *either* remove empty entries, *or* do a case-insensitive split (as an example). This isn't `EmptyEntryOptions` -- these are individual boolean options which apply to the whole process of splitting strings.

Comment: Additionally, the name is plural. Following [Microsoft's guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces?redirectedfrom=MSDN), this means it's probably a flags enum.

Comment: Looks like .Net 5 introduced one of these new options : TrimEntries :)

Answer (score 0):

With [Flags] it is signaled, you should test

```
   StringSplitOptions sso;
   if (sso.HasFlag(StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
   ....
```

rather than

```
   if (sso == StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

The latter test will fail, in case they add more flags.
Code-Tools like Resharper might check for this (I haven't tried it) and mark the latter version as dangerous.

Although for today, they are completly equivalent.

It's a message from the Type Designer to the Type User.
If they add more enum-values, they will number it 2,4,8, rather then 2,3,4. 
This information must be kept somewhere.